# What is the connection between joy and divine love in Rambam's mitzva #3?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, rambam, mitzvah, translation, ahavat-hashem

Ramba"m lists love of God as the third positive commandment in his *Book of Commandments*. It includes the following line, which somehow relates the comprehension of God with joy and the ultimate purpose of loving Him. I am not confident that the punctuation here ([from the very reliable he.wikisource.org](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%92)) is accurate. What does this line correctly mean?

> היא הציווי שנצטווינו על אהבתו יתעלה, והוא: שנתבונן ונסתכל במצוותיו וציווייו ופעולתיו, כדי שנשיגהו ונתענג בהשגתו תכלית התענוג - וזוהי האהבה המצווה [עלינו]‏

Comment: Forget about punctuation. Worry about the translation.

Answer (score 5):

A few lines further down he spells it out more: שבהשתכלות תבוא לידי השגה, וימצא לך תענוג ותבוא האהבה בהכרח - contemplation will lead to understanding, then to enjoyment, which will necessarily result in love. In Hilchos Yesodei Hatorah (2:2) he spells it out further: love of Hashem means pining for His closeness like you would for your beloved (whose company you enjoy). Without that feeling of joy - if you just study the mitzvos and Hashem's actions and so forth as a dry academic subject - how will that lead to love of Him?

Comment: This is anecdotal, but being in a good, joyous mood, isn't it just soooo conducive to love? Purim tonight! Let's test that theory :)